# Retrieving all iterator values from generator function

Tags: python, iterator, generator

Let's say I have a generator function which yields two values:

```
def gen_func():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i, i**2
```

I want to retrieve all iterator values of my function. Currently I use this code snippet for that purpose:

```
x1, x2 = [], []
for a, b in gen_func():
    x1.append(a)
    x2.append(b)
```

This works for me, but seems a little clunky. Is there a more compact way for coding this? I was thinking something like:

```
x1, x2 = map(list, zip(*(a, b for a, b in gen_func())))
```

This, however, just gives me a syntax error.

PS: I am aware that I probably shouldn't use a generator for this purpose, but I need it elsewhere.

**Edit:** Any type for `x1` and `x2` would work, however, I prefer list for my case.

Comment: What is the desired type of x1 and x2? List? Tuple? Anything as long as it's iterable?

Comment: I'd prefer list. Thanks for the remark, I updated my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `x1` and `x2` can be tuples, it's sufficient to do

```
>>> x1, x2 = zip(*gen_func())
>>> x1
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> x2
(0, 1, 4, 9, 16)
```

Otherwise, you could use `map` to apply `list` to the iterator:

```
x1, x2 = map(list, zip(*gen_func()))
```

Just for fun, the same thing can be done using extended iterable unpacking:

```
>>> (*x1,), (*x2,) = zip(*gen_func())
>>> x1
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x2
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice summary of possibilies!

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it:

```
x1, x2 = map(list, zip(*gen_func()))
```